# Blurred profile picture in Android app

Tags: android

I am displaying the Google plus profile picture of the user of my app, but the image is blurred.unless i reduce the size which then makes it almost impossible to recognize who ever is in it.Is there a way to fix this.I am getting the image from a Url.
This is my ImageView

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profilePicture"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:contentDescription="hello"
    android:maxHeight="200dp"
    android:maxWidth="200dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try display image following way,

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profilePicture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="hello"
    android:maxHeight="200dp"
    android:maxWidth="200dp" />
```

Comment: Am sorry but this doesn't help.

Comment: why ? what is the problem with it ? can you please explain ?

Comment: It displays the picture as a small image that can't even be enlarged.

Comment: @OjonugwaOchalifu well if you are straching a small image to large then after some enlarge it surely going to display blurred image. Only if the image has high resolutions then it will display properly, else it gets blurred.

Comment: Yes.You are right.I think that's the problem.Am just wondering why the image is being downloaded in that size.On the web, it is quite large.

Comment: In that case you might be downloading thumbmail. please check it again.

Comment: No it isn't a thumbnail.

Comment: @OjonugwaOchalifu are you sure about this ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47283/discussion-between-ojonugwa-ochalifu-and-user3291365)